# Changing text in h1 on img hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, hover

Im looking for a script in Jquery/Javascript that can change a H1's Content when hovering over a image.

Imagine having 6 different images in a row. When hovering on a image, the change of a h1 would take place.

This is the closest i can get, but i want it to work on Hover, not on click.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
var $li = $("#gallery li");

$li.eq(random % $li.length).addClass("on");
$("h1").text($("img", ".on").attr("alt"));
$("#gallery li").click(function() {
    $("#gallery li").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $("h1").text($("img", ".on").attr("alt"));
});
```

Comment: May I suggest you [**RTFM**](http://api.jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').mouseover(function(){
        var altimg = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('h1').html(altimg);
    });
    $('img').mouseout(function(){
        $('h1').html('');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just got one small question more, if i want the text to like "fade" in a nice way when hovering?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [**`hover`**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with callbacks.

```
$("#gallery li").on('hover', function(e) {
  $("h1").text('Hovered');
 }, function () {
  $("h1").text('back to whatever'); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how you mean.
Linking to my fiddle [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CL9YZ/)

Comment: @user2952613 for fade effect, you can use .fadeToggle() like http://jsfiddle.net/CL9YZ/2/

Comment: Kinda laggy, and the h1 dissapers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

WITH FADE EFFECT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').mouseover(function(){
        var altimg = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('h1').hide();
        $('h1').html(altimg);
        $('h1').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('img').mouseout(function(){
        $('h1').fadeOut(300);
        $('h1').html('');
        $('h1').show();
    });
});
```